# Reuse code in online application and batch processes with Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch, reusability

I've got a question regarding Spring Batch and reusability.

I'm working on a project which is composed of an online application developed with Spring Mvc and several batch processes developed with Spring Batch. Some of the online use cases are also executed in the batch processes.

For example, let's imagine that our online application is Spring's [Sagan app](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan) and the online use case that we want to reuse in batch is [createOrUpdateMemberProfile](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan/blob/8edb30bdda932679367d3f65a53de36b3a8e5f59/sagan-common/src/main/java/sagan/team/support/TeamService.java#L89). From the online application a single member profile is created or updated in each request. However, in the the batch process lots of member profiles are created reading the information from a csv file.

To implement this, the first option is to keep [createOrUpdateMemberProfile](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan/blob/8edb30bdda932679367d3f65a53de36b3a8e5f59/sagan-common/src/main/java/sagan/team/support/TeamService.java#L89) method as it is and develop new code for the batch process with Spring Batch using its ItemWriters and other elements. In this way I'm developing the use case two times, one for online transactions and the second for batch processes.

The second option is to reuse [createOrUpdateMemberProfile](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan/blob/8edb30bdda932679367d3f65a53de36b3a8e5f59/sagan-common/src/main/java/sagan/team/support/TeamService.java#L89) method in the batch process with [ItemWriterAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#reusingExistingServices). In this way I'm reusing the online method, but I guess I'm losing some performance because I'm getting rid of [chunk-oriented processing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/step.html#chunkOrientedProcessing). Depending on the amount of member profiles to create from the csv file, it might be a bit risky.

The third, and last, option is to get rid of [createOrUpdateMemberProfile](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan/blob/8edb30bdda932679367d3f65a53de36b3a8e5f59/sagan-common/src/main/java/sagan/team/support/TeamService.java#L89) method and implement the batch process with Spring Batch which be called from the online application as well. That is, the online application will launch the job, but instead of creating many member profiles it will create just one. In this way I'm reusing code, but it sounds really strange to me and I discard it beforehand.

Right now I'm keen on the second option but I wonder if I'm loosing something, apart from performance, or I'll struggle with another aspect that I'm not aware of. Any advice or suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I would also use option 2. I don't see why there would be a performance issue in the batch job because there will be a single transaction for the whole chunk.

Comment: I was wrong. As you say, with option 2 there would be a single transaction for the whole chunk.  What I really meant to say is that I can't use [batch updates](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/batchupdate.html), in other words, for every row there will be an insert operation. In addition, if there is a service rest call in the method, which can be slow, the chunk transaction might be longer than desired and can lead to other problems. So, I guess it is a trade-off between performance and reusability.

Comment: The `JdbcBatchItemWriter` uses batch updates so that's not an issue.